# Differential Equation on Temperature Change

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

So I have a question which I have been struggling to solve and from what I can tell, it uses differential equation but I am just unsure of how to implement the question into a differential equation and then solve it. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

A chemical solution is resting at a temperature of 73 degrees Celsius. The solution is placed in a freezer which is at a constant temperature of -15 degrees Celsius to crystallize. If it takes 30 minutes for the temperature of the mixture to drop to 25 degrees Celsius, how much longer will it take for the mixture to reach 0 degrees Celsius?

Comment: I don't think you need a differential equation for this.

Comment: Hint: the time curve is probably an exponential $T = T_f + C e^{- \lambda t}$ at time $t$.

Comment: I think I can see how it would be done without the use of a differential equation however, the area I got the question from is focused on differential equations and I think it's after the rate of change.

Comment: Possibly related, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420007/can-i-please-have-help-to-find-the-solution-to-this-exponential-growth-decay-w/2420017#2420017

Comment: Look up "Newton's Law of cooling". This is described by a first order DE and the information given will let you calculate the rate constant for its solution. you can then calculate the time required.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, turns out the curve was exponential and by subbing in the values into an exponential equation I got the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The  [Newton's law of cooling](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/first-order-differential-equations/exponential-models-diff-eq/v/newtons-law-of-cooling)  states the following ODE for temperature changes:
$$\frac{dT}{dt} \propto T-T_a$$
or$$\frac{dT}{dt}=-k(T-T_a)\ \ \ \ \ \ldots (i)$$
(Here the use of minus sign is due to the fact that the temperature is decreasing.)

In this ODE, $t$ is the time, $T(t)$ is the temperature at time $t$ and $T_a$ is the temperature of the object's environment. In your case $T_a$ is the temperature of the freezer i.e $T_a=-15$. The Initial Value Conditions for your problem are
$$T(0)=73,\ T(30)=25$$
The solution of the ODE $(i)$ is
$$T=T_a+ce^{-kt}$$
$$T=-15+ce^{-kt}$$
By using $T(0)=73$, we get 
$$c=88$$
So
$$T=88e^{-kt}-15$$
Putting $T(30)=25$,
$$e^{-30k}=\frac{40}{88}$$
$$k=\frac{\ln\frac{40}{88}}{-30}\approx0.02628$$
So $$T=88e^{-0.02628t}-15$$

Now we have to fing the value of $t=t_\circ$ such that $T(t_\circ)=0$. So
$$88e^{-0.02628t_\circ}-15=0$$
$$t_\circ=\frac{\ln\frac{15}{88}}{-0.02628}\approx67.32$$
So almost 67 minutes after the initial time ($t=0$), the solution has temperature $0$degrees.